# Rendering bitmap image from buffer

Tags: c, bitmap, bmp

I have a script that uses `fread` to copy a bmp data to a buffer type `byte** BUFF;`
I use the buffer with the format of: `BUFF[nImages][Data];` after the dynamic alocation.
That part works well, however...

The problem is when i try to render the content. The image goes curved, as you can see on the left. The image on the right is the original one.
[image: Right one is the original]

The code i use to render the image is:

```
word ofs = 54;

byte sgetc (byte *str)
{
    return str[ofs++];
}

void bmp_drawfbuff ()
{
    word WIDTH, HEIGHT, W, H;
    byte R, G, B;

    HEIGHT = BMPDATA[0][18] + BMPDATA[0][19] * 256;
    WIDTH = BMPDATA[0][22] + BMPDATA[0][23] * 256;

    for(W=0; W<WIDTH; W++)
    {
        for(H=0; H<HEIGHT; H++)
        {
            B = sgetc(BMPDATA[0]);
            G = sgetc(BMPDATA[0]);
            R = sgetc(BMPDATA[0]);


            setpen(R, G, B, 0, 1);
            putpixel(W, H);
        }
    }
}
```

Just to note that the same code, with `fseek` and `fgetc` works, when rendering directly from a file. What am i doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like something is wrong with image dimensions.
Width is smaller than is should be.
<s>Try to swap WIDTH and WIDTH here:</s>

```
HEIGHT = BMPDATA[0][18] + BMPDATA[0][19] * 256;
WIDTH = BMPDATA[0][22] + BMPDATA[0][23] * 256;
```

Then, you need to swap counter variables inside `for`s, I think:

```
for(W=0; H<WIDTH; W++)
{
    for(H=0; W<HEIGHT; H++)
    {
```

**Explanation:**

```
Let's assume that you have 10x9 image:

  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 --------------------
2 --[]----------------
3 --[]------------[]--
4 --[]------------[]--
5 --[][][][][][][][]--
6 ------[]------------
7 ------[]------------
8 ------[]------------
9 ------[]------------
```

Inside .bmp it's stored as 1D array:

```
----------------------[]------------------[]------------[]----[]------------[]----[][][][][][][][]--------[]------------------[]------------------[]------------------[]------------
```

If you would treat it as 9x10 image (instead of 10x9) you would see this:

```
------------------
----[]------------
------[]----------
--[]----[]--------
----[]----[][][][]
[][][][]--------[]
------------------
[]----------------
--[]--------------
----[]------------
```

Vertical lines `|` turned into diagonal ones `\`.
You have the same effect on your picture.

Comment: `WIDTH` returns 500, `HEIGHT` returns 460
This is the exact image size. The problem is not in here. Just don't pay attention to the comparison picture.

Comment: In fact, that picture is very informative. First, try to swap counters between two `for`s.

Comment: Updated, it seems to work, i don't know, how could i miss to swap them though. Now i guess.. i have to touch the `for` loops once again to make the image properly rotated.

Comment: Your two for-loops need another look :)

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Bitmap_file_header

gives the height at offset 22 - you are reading offset 18 as height

Comment: P, you are in mistake, i advice you to look carefuly once again. If you are trying to say my height position is wrong.

Comment: HEIGHT = BMPDATA[0][18] + BMPDATA[0][19] * 256; // <- questions code

Windows BITMAPINFOHEADER[2]

18 4 the bitmap width in pixels (signed integer) 
22 4 the bitmap height in pixels (signed integer)

Comment: Thats for width, i just swiped the for loop, where it work'd. Doesn't matter. I will have to rate it. Yes, i know. I will consider your suggest as a second solution.

Comment: from your first image you can see that each line is right shifted by 40px, once you posted the width and height it became more visible, hence the result is x & y mixed up if you swap the loops over - i.e. rotation - at least that's what's my old farts brain came up with.

Comment: Yes, width and height were pretty much swapped. I'm just glad its that, and its not in my code.